# Android Studio - TextView check content

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I check the content of a TextView?

At first I declare my TextView (MainActivity):

```
private TextView contentTxt1;
contentTxt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_text1);
```

Set the Text (strings.xml):

```
<string name="scan_text">Lorem</string>
```

Then I check its content (MainActivity):

```
if(contentTxt1.getText() == "Lorem"){

//Do Something
}
```

But when I debug my application now, the variables watcher shows me the following:

```
contentTxt1.getText() == "Lorem" = false
```

Okay, so it seems the content isn't "Lorem", maybe it's empty. But at the same time it shows me:

```
contentTxt1.getText() == "Lorem"
```

("Lorem is green")

What should I do now? Am I checking it wrong? I guess it's a simple but stupid mistake by me.

Comment: "Lorem is green" is not the same as "Lorem" maybe you want to use contains?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `.equals()` method instead of `==` to compare two strings.

More: https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-strings